# Why is my release log empty in Heroku even though I run echo?

Tags: heroku

This is my working `heroku.yml` file:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - echo I want to see if this actually works and appears in the logs
```

When I check the release logs in the website, or even via cli with `Heroku releases:output -a [my-app] v18` it shows nothing

Is there a way that we can actually see something? It's really hard to debug what's going on and whether my script is running or not if I can't even see the release log. I can still see the build log as usual, just not the release log

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case, the cause was that `curl` was not installed in my Docker image.
I found the following log by `heroku logs -t`:

```
app[release.6892]: /bin/sh: curl: not found
```

It seems Heroku uses `curl` to send logs. Installing `curl` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with containers without curl as explained by @Ryu.

As a workaround you can see the release logs in the normal app logs.